# IP list for Azure DevOps whitelisting

Tags: azure, azure-devops, whitelist, azure-nsg

Does anyone know if there is any documentation for the list of IPs I have to whitelist to get callbacks from Azure DevOps? I cannot seem to find any list, not can I find any tag in an Azure NSG to apply.

Comment: duplicate with this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53422395/how-to-get-the-ip-address-for-azure-devops-hosted-agents-to-add-to-the-white-lis

Comment: not really, that is the thread to get the hosted agent and Azure Datacenter Ips, which is not my issue. I would like to have the IP list of Azure DevOps services, so that when I get a callback, I can have the Ips whitelisted. Azure Datacenter IPs are a superset of it, but I rather have a smaller IP list to whitelist. Azure Datacenter IPs include every IPs (including user vms).

Answer (score 0):

There is a list of IPs at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/migrate/migration-import?view=azure-devops#azure-devops-services-ips. Not sure if relevant for you scenario.

Comment: looks like these are only related to the migration service, and not the whole list of Azure DevOps IPs. I added the ips in that list, and still my scenario doesnt light up.