# Publishing artifacts to an external server

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

We are using azure devops pipeline to build our application including a Azure build agent. At the end of this process, I would like to publish the artifacts to an on-premise server shared directory (which will connect to  company mandated deployment process (repliweb)).
Is that possible?
Looking at the documentation it looks like I can use publish artifact or copy file step (or maybe even ftp).
Our IT organization needs to know the IP/port so that the firewall rules can be authored.
Where can I get that information?

I suppose the other possibility would be have our server pull the artifact from Azure devops.

Comment: if you need a deterministic IP where the request is coming from (for example when you use the upload-ftp comman), you need to host your own build agent (which can then have a fixed IP)

Comment: @JenL Not get your latest information, is the workaround helpful for you?If so,you could [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). Or if you have any concern, feel free to share it here.

Answer (score 1):

> Publishing artifacts to an external server

For this issue, you can try to use `FTP Upload task` in the pipeline. Using this task in a build or release pipeline to upload files to a remote machine using the File Transfer Protocol (FTP), or securely with FTPS.

[image]

For details,please refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/ftp-upload?view=azure-devops).

Comment: We need to configure the firewall rules for the target external server which means we need to know the originating IP address for the azure devops build agent. How do I discover this? Is the IP/IP range consistent enough to define a range in our firewall rules?

Comment: You can refer to this [case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53422395/how-to-get-the-ip-address-for-azure-devops-hosted-agents-to-add-to-the-white-lis) on how to get the IP Address for Azure DevOps Hosted Agents and this [blog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/new-ip-firewall-rules-for-azure-devops/).Hope this helps :)