# Whitelisting Azure Devops IPs for Service Hooks

Tags: triggers, azure-devops, webhooks, pull-request, azure-service-hooks

Everywhere I looked I was unable to find the IPs to whitelist for a Service Hook that reaches back to our internal network from Azure Devops. I was able to get it to work by making the request and looking at the logs what IP was blocked. I then went to ARIN and looked up the IPs and found the blocks that Microsoft is using for this service.

As of 3/10/2020 -

Net Range
20.33.0.0 - 20.128.255.255
CIDR
20.33.0.0/16
20.34.0.0/15
20.36.0.0/14
20.40.0.0/13
20.48.0.0/12
20.64.0.0/10
20.128.0.0/16

Answer (score 1):

> Whitelisting Azure Devops IPs for Service Hooks

Sorry for any inconvenience.

At present, there is no specified Azure DevOps Service Hooks IP address.
You could try to add Azure DevOps IP addresses:

[Allowed address lists and network connections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/allow-list-ip-url?view=azure-devops)

But, that is Azure Datacenter Ips, Azure Datacenter IPs are a superset of it, but if you want have a smaller IP list to white list, there is a suggestion ticket about that feature:

[Webhooks (service hook) inbound IP whitelist](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/913876/webhooks-service-hook-inbound-ip-whitelist-1.html)

You could vote and add your comments for this feedback.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Leo, but to my understanding Azure DevOps Server will not facilitate service hooks from Azure DevOps to on-prem services such as Jenkins.

Comment: @AshwinPrasad, Yes, you are right. I ignored the key point of service hooks, I updated the answer to remove the incorrect part. Thanks for you reminding.