# Azure devops - get agent ip address

Tags: azure, azure-devops, ip, azure-pipelines

I have a azure devops pipeline that runs 2 jobs - one on windows agent running a server, the other on Linux agent - running a client that connects to the server. These jobs run in parallel. Currently ip address and port are hard coded on client side repo. But I want to decouple this situation.
is there a way in azure devops pipeline to get agent ip in the first job, store it in variable and use it as parameter to a step in the second job?

thanks a lot for all the help.

Comment: You could use `Powershell` or bash to get IP address, however it keeps changing. see this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53422395/how-to-get-the-ip-address-for-azure-devops-hosted-agents-to-add-to-the-white-lis)

Comment: Thank you! I’ll save that link answer for later. Currently we are not running on cloud. But we also do not have internet connection on build machines, will ipinfo work?

Comment: Without internet connection, you wouldn't be able to reach ipinfo.io, so need to use Powershell command,  `Get-NetIPAddress`, see [this](https://www.delftstack.com/howto/powershell/powershell-get-ip-address/) for some ideas.

Comment: If the jobs are running *in parallel*, no; you'd need to find some other way to let the client job know the ip address. But it might be possible, with a bit of restructuring. Could you have stage 1 where a small job runs on the server just to find out the ip address and port, then stage 2 (using those values) runs the two jobs (server and client)?